# Spring DataIntegrityViolationException in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have interesting problem with this code:

```
package com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.repository;

import com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.entity.*;
import com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.tools.creator.ProductSaleCreator;
import com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.tools.creator.SaleReceiptCreator;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/application-test.properties",
        properties = "server.port=8081")
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class SaleReceiptRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductSaleRepository productSaleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SaleReceiptRepository saleReceiptRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductBarcodeRepository productBarcodeRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductSalePricesRepository productSalePricesRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private static final String staticReceiptNumber = "14123123";


    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach(){
        productSaleRepository.deleteAll();
        saleReceiptRepository.deleteAll();
        productRepository.deleteAll();
        productBarcodeRepository.deleteAll();
        customerRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Add receipt")
    @Order(1)
    @Transactional
    public void givenEntityReceipt_thenAdd_thenReturnReceiptEntity(){
        SaleReceipt receipt = saveReferencesAndSet();
        SaleReceipt savedReceipt = saleReceiptRepository.save(receipt);

        // Assert
        assertThat(savedReceipt)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .isEqualTo(receipt);


    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get receipt by number")
    @Order(2)
    @Transactional
    public void givenReceiptNumber_whenFind_thenReturnEntity(){
        SaleReceipt receipt = saveReferencesAndSet();
        SaleReceipt savedReceipt = saleReceiptRepository.save(receipt);

        SaleReceipt getFromDB = saleReceiptRepository.findByNumber(staticReceiptNumber);
        System.out.println("FUDGE: " + getFromDB);
        // Assert
        assertNotNull(getFromDB);
        assertThat(getFromDB)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .isEqualTo(savedReceipt);
    }


    /* --------------------------------- PRIVATE METHODS --------------------------------- */
    private SaleReceipt saveReferencesAndSet() {
        SaleReceipt receipt = SaleReceiptCreator.entity();
        Customer customer = customerRepository.save(receipt.getCustomer());
        receipt.setCustomer(customer);
        List<ProductSale> productSales = ProductSaleCreator.entityList();

        for(ProductSale productSale: productSales) {
            arrangeProduct(productSale);
        }

        receipt.setProductSaleList(productSales);

        return receipt;
    }

    private void arrangeProduct(ProductSale productSaleEntity){
        var productEntity = productSaleEntity.getProduct();

        ProductCategory productCategory = productCategoryRepository.save(productEntity.getCategory());
        Company productCompany = companyRepository.save(productEntity.getCompany());
        List<ProductSalePrice> productSalePrice =
                productSalePricesRepository.saveAll(productEntity.getProductSalePrices());
        List<ProductBarcode> productBarcodeList =
                productBarcodeRepository.saveAll(productEntity.getProductBarcodeList());
        Product productSaved = productRepository.save(productEntity);

        productEntity.setProductBarcodeList(productBarcodeList);
        productEntity.setProductSalePrices(productSalePrice);
        productEntity.setCategory(productCategory);
        productEntity.setCompany(productCompany);
    }




}
```

When I run class I mean all test cases second method always fail. But I run methods seperatedly pass all.
For second method error is :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKJNRBBF8CSJYWHM3L6R58M78AV: PUBLIC.PRODUCT_SALES FOREIGN KEY(SALE_RECEIPT_NUMBER) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SALE_RECEIPTS(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
/* insert for com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.entity.ProductSale */insert into product_sales (bonus,comment,created_date,discount_decimal,discount_percent,is_active,product_id,quantity,sale_receipt_number,sale_price,sa [23506-224]] [/* insert for com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.entity.ProductSale */insert into product_sales (bonus,comment,created_date,discount_decimal,discount_percent,is_active,product_id,quantity,sale_receipt_number,sale_price,sale_status,updated_date,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default)]; SQL [/* insert for com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.entity.ProductSale */insert into product_sales (bonus,comment,created_date,discount_decimal,discount_percent,is_active,product_id,quantity,sale_receipt_number,sale_price,sale_status,updated_date,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default)]; constraint [FKJNRBBF8CSJYWHM3L6R58M78AV]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:290)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy163.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.repository.SaleReceiptRepositoryTest.givenReceiptNumber_whenFind_thenReturnEntity(SaleReceiptRepositoryTest.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKJNRBBF8CSJYWHM3L6R58M78AV: PUBLIC.PRODUCT_SALES FOREIGN KEY(SALE_RECEIPT_NUMBER) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SALE_RECEIPTS(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
/* insert for com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.entity.ProductSale */insert into product_sales (bonus,comment,created_date,discount_decimal,discount_percent,is_active,product_id,quantity,sale_receipt_number,sale_price,sa [23506-224]] [/* insert for com.mstockRestAPI.mstockRestAPI.entity.ProductSale */insert into product_sales (bonus,comment,created_date,discount_decimal,discount_percent,is_active,product_id,quantity,sale_receipt_number,sale_price,sale_status,updated_date,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default)]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturn.....
```

I searched everywhere and asked to chatgpt but no result.

Comment: Please remember to remove offensive language from your code.

Comment: Sorry. I was angry just I wrote. Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that you are trying to insert a duplicate sale_receipt_number and this should be unique since is refereced as a foreign key.